# How to scrape all match / ticket info while iterating a list?

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Thanks in advance guys - I'm trying to compile ticket sale information into one easy to read list or possibly filtered table, but one step at a time.

Successfully managed to write a short script to list the pages for each event:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.liverpoolfc.com/tickets/tickets-availability"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

pages = []
for link in soup.find_all("a", class_="ticket-card fixture"):
    href = link.get("href")
    if href:
        pages.append(href)

print("Pages:")
for page in set(pages):
    print("- " + page)
```

Which returns

```
Pages:
- /tickets/tickets-availability/wolverhampton-wanderers-v-liverpool-fc-4-feb-2023-0300pm-245
- /tickets/tickets-availability/liverpool-fc-v-arsenal-8-apr-2023-0300pm-236
- /tickets/tickets-availability/liverpool-fc-v-manchester-united-4-mar-2023-0300pm-235
- /tickets/tickets-availability/liverpool-fc-v-real-madrid-21-feb-2023-0800pm-238
- /tickets/tickets-availability/liverpool-fc-v-tottenham-hotspur-29-apr-2023-0300pm-232
- /tickets/tickets-availability/liverpool-fc-v-nottingham-forest-22-apr-2023-0300pm-234
- /tickets/tickets-availability/liverpool-fc-v-fulham-18-mar-2023-0300pm-237
- /tickets/tickets-availability/newcastle-united-v-liverpool-fc-18-feb-2023-0530pm-246
- /tickets/tickets-availability/liverpool-fc-v-brentford-6-may-2023-0300pm-231
- /tickets/tickets-availability/liverpool-fc-v-aston-villa-20-may-2023-0300pm-230
- /tickets/tickets-availability/liverpool-fc-v-everton-13-feb-2023-0800pm-233
- /tickets/tickets-availability/crystal-palace-v-liverpool-fc-25-feb-2023-0745pm-247
```

So far so good.

But for the following code I'm only getting the first results and hoping to get about 4 sets, and trying find all just doesn't seem to work (this is just for a single page at the moment):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.liverpoolfc.com/tickets/tickets-availability/liverpool-fc-v-everton-13-feb-2023-0800pm-233"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

# Find all the elements with the desired class
ticket_sales = soup.find_all(class_="accorMenu")

# Create a list to store the extracted information
sales_list = []

# Check if any ticket sales were found
if ticket_sales:
    # Iterate over each ticket sale
    for accorMenuList in ticket_sales:
        # Extract the desired information from the ticket sale
        saletype = soup.find("span", class_="saletype").text.strip()
        salename = soup.find("span", class_="salename").text.strip()
        prereqs = soup.find("span", class_="prereqs").text.strip()
        status = soup.find("span", class_="status").text.strip()
        whenavailable = soup.find("span", class_="whenavailable").text.strip()

        # Store the extracted information in a dictionary
        sale_info = {
            "saletype": saletype,
            "salename": salename,
            "prereqs": prereqs,
            "status": status,
            "whenavailable": whenavailable
        }

        # Add the dictionary to the list of sales
        sales_list.append(sale_info)

    # Print the list of sales
    for sale in sales_list:
        print("Saletype:", sale["saletype"])
        print("Salename:", sale["salename"])
        print("Prereqs:", sale["prereqs"])
        print("Status:", sale["status"])
        print("Whenavailable:", sale["whenavailable"])
        print("---")
else:
    # If no ticket sales were found, print a message
    print("No ticket sales found.")
```

returns:

```
Saletype: match ticket -
Salename: Hospitality
Prereqs:
Status: available
Whenavailable: Mon 6 Feb 2023, 11:00am

---
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - By far a very well outlined first question, which gets by without any images, but provides the necessary code as text, where it comes to the problem - **Well done**. *So that your future questions get a little more focus a few reading tips [tour], [ask], [mcve] these can also help in matters of formatting*. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is already the right one, but you are subject to the following misconceptions:

- `ticket_sales = soup.find_all(class_="accorMenu")` does not reference the individual list elements but the list itself, which leads to the fact that there is only one element in the `ResultSet` that can be iterated over.

  Instead use `soup.select('.accorMenu li')` or
  `soup.select('.accorMenu h3')` to select the individual containers.

  *Used [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) here, because it makes chaining a bit easier than use of several `find()/find_all()*
- When iterating, do not reference `soup` to the global object `saletype = soup.find("span", class_="saletype").text.strip()` but reference the respective iteration. Otherwise you will still only get the information of the first element in `soup`.
- Furthermore, you should always check if an element has been found at all before applying a method to it, this can be implemented with a simple `if else statement`

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.liverpoolfc.com/tickets/tickets-availability/liverpool-fc-v-everton-13-feb-2023-0800pm-233'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

sales_list = []

for e in soup.select('.accorMenu h3'):
    # Store the extracted information in a dictionary
    sales_list.append({
        "saletype": e.find("span", class_="saletype").text.strip(),
        "salename": e.find("span", class_="salename").text.strip(),
        "prereqs": e.find("span", class_="prereqs").text.strip(),
        "status": e.find("span", class_="status").text.strip(),
        "whenavailable": e.find("span", class_="whenavailable").text.strip() if e.find("span", class_="whenavailable") else None
    })

sales_list
```

##### Output

```
[{'saletype': 'match ticket -',
  'salename': 'Hospitality',
  'prereqs': '',
  'status': 'available',
  'whenavailable': None},
 {'saletype': 'match ticket -',
  'salename': 'Local Members Sale',
  'prereqs': 'Members with an ‘L’ Postcode',
  'status': 'sold out',
  'whenavailable': None},
 {'saletype': 'match ticket -',
  'salename': 'Local General Sale',
  'prereqs': 'Supporters with an ‘L’ Postcode',
  'status': 'sold out',
  'whenavailable': None},
 {'saletype': 'match ticket -',
  'salename': 'Additional Members Sale',
  'prereqs': 'Members who have recorded 4+ Premier League home games from either season 2018/19 or 2019/20',
  'status': 'on sale soon',
  'whenavailable': 'Mon 6 Feb 2023, 11:00am'}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm going to try this out soon but you've already helped my understanding improve. Cheers!